# Возвращается значение NaN

Tags: javascript

У меня такой код (js):

```
        function culc(count){
                if(count >= 1000){
                    var l = count.lenght - 3;
                    var n = "1e" + l;
                    var ec = Math.round(count/n) * n;
                    var ans = ec.toString().replace(/000/g, "K");
                    alert(ans);
                    return ans;
                }else{
                    alert(count);
                    return count;
                }
        }
```

Почему возвращается значение NaN?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Проблема в этой строке:

```
var l = count.lenght - 3;  // NaN
```

---

А т.к. `l` имеет значение `NaN`, то любые операции с `NaN` приводят к `NaN`

Теперь как получился `NaN`.

Переменная `count`, похоже, число. У чисел нет свойства `lenght`, поэтому `count.lenght` вернул значение `undefined`. А `undefined - 3` вернет `NaN`.

**UPD.** Как **Igor** заметил у вас в коде опечатка слова `length`, поэтому даже если такой метод и был у чисел, `count.lenght` вернул бы `undefined`, т.к. опечатка в названии.

Предполагаю, что рабочий код будет такой:

```
var l = count.toString().length - 3;
```

---

**PS.**

[NaN (англ. Not-a-Number, «нечисло»)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN)

Comment: а опечатка в `lenght`?

Comment: А я и не обратил внимания на опечатку )